# Source Code call from WEB

Tags: android

i am very very new on this section and have a question.

I have a App with a Menu. The File name is NavItem.java and have this code:

```
package de.digisocken.anotherrss;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by chhatbardevangi on 3/31/18.
 */

public class NavItem {

public static final int TYPE_HEADER = 1;
public static final int TYPE_ROW = 2;

public static final int TYPE_WEB = 1;
public static final int TYPE_RSS = 2;

private String label, url;
private int icon;
private int itemType = TYPE_HEADER;
private int linkType = TYPE_WEB;

public NavItem(int itemType, String label, int icon, String url, int linkType) {
    this.itemType = itemType;
    this.label = label;
    this.icon = icon;
    this.url = url;
    this.linkType = linkType;
}

public String getLabel() {
    return label;
}

public void setLabel(String label) {
    this.label = label;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public int getIcon() {
    return icon;
}

public void setIcon(int icon) {
    this.icon = icon;
}

public int getItemType() {
    return itemType;
}

public void setItemType(int itemType) {
    this.itemType = itemType;
}

public int getLinkType() {
    return linkType;
}

public void setLinkType(int linkType) {
    this.linkType = linkType;
}

public static ArrayList<NavItem> getDrawerItems() {
    ArrayList<NavItem> mListItem = new ArrayList<>();

    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_HEADER, "Category 1", 0, null, 0));
    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_ROW, "Wiki", R.drawable.ic_language, "https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amstetten", TYPE_WEB));
    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_ROW, "Gemeinde WEB", R.drawable.ic_language, "http://www.amstetten.noe.gv.at/", TYPE_WEB));

    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_HEADER, "Category 2", 0, null, 0));
    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_ROW, "Bezirksblätter", R.drawable.ic_rss_feed, "https://www.meinbezirk.at/feed/action/mode/realm/ID/281/", TYPE_RSS));
    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_ROW, "Nön", R.drawable.ic_rss_feed, "http://www.noen.at/amstetten/xml/rss", TYPE_RSS));
    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_ROW, "Nön website", R.drawable.ic_language, "http://www.noen.at/amstetten/", TYPE_WEB));
    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_ROW, "Test", R.drawable.ic_rss_feed, "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/rss.xml", TYPE_RSS));

    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_HEADER, "Category 3", 0, null, 0));
    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_ROW, "Übersicht", R.drawable.ic_language, "http://www.feuerwehr-krems.at/ShowArtikelSpeed.asp?Artikel=5184&Filter=01", TYPE_WEB));
    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_ROW, "Rückblick", R.drawable.ic_language, "http://www.feuerwehr-krems.at/ShowArtikelSpeed.asp?Artikel=7273&filter=01", TYPE_WEB));
    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_HEADER, "Category 1", 0, null, 0));
    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_ROW, "Wiki", R.drawable.ic_language, "https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amstetten", TYPE_WEB));
    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_ROW, "Gemeinde WEB", R.drawable.ic_language, "http://www.amstetten.noe.gv.at/", TYPE_WEB));

    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_HEADER, "Category 2", 0, null, 0));
    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_ROW, "Bezirksblätter", R.drawable.ic_rss_feed, "https://www.meinbezirk.at/feed/action/mode/realm/ID/281/", TYPE_RSS));
    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_ROW, "Nön", R.drawable.ic_rss_feed, "http://www.noen.at/amstetten/xml/rss", TYPE_RSS));
    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_ROW, "Nön website", R.drawable.ic_language, "http://www.noen.at/amstetten/", TYPE_WEB));
    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_ROW, "Test", R.drawable.ic_rss_feed, "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/rss.xml", TYPE_RSS));

    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_HEADER, "Category 3", 0, null, 0));
    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_ROW, "Übersicht", R.drawable.ic_language, "http://www.feuerwehr-krems.at/ShowArtikelSpeed.asp?Artikel=5184&Filter=01", TYPE_WEB));
    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_ROW, "Rückblick", R.drawable.ic_language, "http://www.feuerwehr-krems.at/ShowArtikelSpeed.asp?Artikel=7273&filter=01", TYPE_WEB));
    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_HEADER, "Category 1", 0, null, 0));
    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_ROW, "Wiki", R.drawable.ic_language, "https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amstetten", TYPE_WEB));
    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_ROW, "Gemeinde WEB", R.drawable.ic_language, "http://www.amstetten.noe.gv.at/", TYPE_WEB));

    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_HEADER, "Category 2", 0, null, 0));
    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_ROW, "Bezirksblätter", R.drawable.ic_rss_feed, "https://www.meinbezirk.at/feed/action/mode/realm/ID/281/", TYPE_RSS));
    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_ROW, "Nön", R.drawable.ic_rss_feed, "http://www.noen.at/amstetten/xml/rss", TYPE_RSS));
    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_ROW, "Nön website", R.drawable.ic_language, "http://www.noen.at/amstetten/", TYPE_WEB));
    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_ROW, "Test", R.drawable.ic_rss_feed, "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/rss.xml", TYPE_RSS));

    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_HEADER, "Category 3", 0, null, 0));
    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_ROW, "Übersicht", R.drawable.ic_language, "http://www.feuerwehr-krems.at/ShowArtikelSpeed.asp?Artikel=5184&Filter=01", TYPE_WEB));
    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_ROW, "Rückblick", R.drawable.ic_language, "http://www.feuerwehr-krems.at/ShowArtikelSpeed.asp?Artikel=7273&filter=01", TYPE_WEB));
    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_HEADER, "Category 1", 0, null, 0));
    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_ROW, "Wiki", R.drawable.ic_language, "https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amstetten", TYPE_WEB));
    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_ROW, "Gemeinde WEB", R.drawable.ic_language, "http://www.amstetten.noe.gv.at/", TYPE_WEB));

    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_HEADER, "Category 2", 0, null, 0));
    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_ROW, "Bezirksblätter", R.drawable.ic_rss_feed, "https://www.meinbezirk.at/feed/action/mode/realm/ID/281/", TYPE_RSS));
    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_ROW, "Nön", R.drawable.ic_rss_feed, "http://www.noen.at/amstetten/xml/rss", TYPE_RSS));
    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_ROW, "Nön website", R.drawable.ic_language, "http://www.noen.at/amstetten/", TYPE_WEB));
    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_ROW, "Test", R.drawable.ic_rss_feed, "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/rss.xml", TYPE_RSS));

    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_HEADER, "Category 3", 0, null, 0));
    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_ROW, "Übersicht", R.drawable.ic_language, "http://www.feuerwehr-krems.at/ShowArtikelSpeed.asp?Artikel=5184&Filter=01", TYPE_WEB));
    mListItem.add(new NavItem(TYPE_ROW, "Rückblick", R.drawable.ic_language, "http://www.feuerwehr-krems.at/ShowArtikelSpeed.asp?Artikel=7273&filter=01", TYPE_WEB));

    return mListItem;

}
}
```

is it possible thath i upload this file on the web and the app call it from a link? If yes what wold be the new code?

Comment: If i understood you correctly you need to use [DeepLink](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html)

Comment: Seems no. A java file needs to be compiled as a part of a java package before being used. It doesn't make sense if you pack a java compiler within your app. Instead you can place already compiled jar,apk or dex files online. Then you can download them and invoke methods within. However this is complicated and in many cases it's not a good idea to do so.

Comment: I noticed that your code can be seperated into a config file and codes that get data from config files. You can have **static** code and **dynamic** config.

Comment: Look into instant apps